# Count Clicks using javascript for Multiple Button

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface

This code counts 'clicks' for only first Product in the list fetch from the database but how they can produce 'clicks count' for Remaining products

```
 <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yii2_advanced");

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM product");

$dynamicList ="";
WHILE ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):


   $idr = $rows['product_id'];
   $product_name = $rows['product_name'];
   $product_amount = $rows['product_amount'];
   $product_type = $rows['product_type'];
    $dynamicList .= '   <script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
function onClick2(){

    if(clicks >0){
        clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

}
else if(clicks == 0){

    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

}
};
</script>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <tr>
      <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="'. $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
      <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
        Rs.' . $product_amount . '<br />
         <button onClick="onClick2()" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
<p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks">0</a></p>
<button onClick="onClick()"><b>+</b></button>

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
   endwhile;
   ?>
```

For better illustration I will show you image below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/574mL1z1/1/

Comment: 1) don't tag `jquery` then use `document.getElementById`.  2) wire up your events via jquery instead of `onclick=`, that way you get a `this`.  3) use classes instead of IDs 4) store the click count on the element, not as a single global 5) use `this` to get the relevant clicks box `$(this).closest("td").find("a").text(clicks)`

Comment: You need to change your fiddle's javascript option to 'no wrap' (either option) otherwise the functions are private (did you test the fiddle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
    var clicks = {0:0, 1:0};

    function onClick(index) {
      clicks[index] += 1;
      console.log(index);
      document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];
    }

    function onClick2(index) {

      if (clicks[index] > 0) {
        clicks[index] -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];

      } else if (clicks[index] == 0) {

        document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];

      }
    }
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="'. $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
    <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '
      <br /> Rs.' . $product_amount . '
      <br />
      <button onclick="javascript:onClick2(0)" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
      <p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks0">0</a></p>
      <button onclick="javascript:onClick(0)"><b>+</b></button>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="'. $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
    <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '
      <br /> Rs.' . $product_amount . '
      <br />
      <button onClick="onClick2(1);" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
      <p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks1">0</a></p>
      <button onClick="onClick(1);"><b>+</b></button>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 1 FOR multiple items**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yii2_advanced");

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM product");

$dynamicList = "";
$index = 0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
  $idr = $rows['product_id'];
  $product_name = $rows['product_name'];
  $product_amount = $rows['product_amount'];
  $product_type = $rows['product_type'];
  $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <tr>
      <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="' . $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
      <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
        Rs.' . $product_amount . '<br />
         <button onClick="onClick2(' . $index . ')" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
<p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks">0</a></p>
<button onClick="onClick(' . $index . ')"><b>+</b></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
  $index++;
endwhile;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicks = <?php json_encode(array_fill(0, ($index - 1), 0)); ?>;
  function onClick(index){
    clicks[index] += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];
  }

  function onClick2(index){
    if(clicks[index] > 0){
      clicks[index] -= 1;
      document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];
    }else if(clicks == 0){
      document.getElementById("clicks" + index).innerHTML = clicks[index];
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It is for two can u provide code for multiple products using php in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Modified your fiddle with jQuery and cleaned PHP like: https://jsfiddle.net/574mL1z1/2/

The key problems are two:

1. You were trying to update same variable (`clicks`) on click of `+` and `-` buttons of both the products.
2. Somehow the code you are using in the fiddle for calling JS functions is not working.

### I think in a cleaner way you can try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="'. $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            Rs.' . $product_amount . '<br />
             <button class="dec" data-id="id1" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
             <p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks_id1">0</a></p>
             <button type="button" data-id="id1" class="inc"><b>+</b></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="%" valign="top"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="'. $idr . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
             Rs.' . $product_amount . '<br />
             <button class="dec" data-id="id2" type="button"><b>-</b></button>
             <p style="display:inline-block;"><a id="clicks_id2">0</a></p>
             <button type="button" data-id="id2" class="inc"><b>+</b></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".inc").on("click", function (){
    var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var clicks = parseInt($("a#clicks_"+dataId).html());
    clicks++;
    $("a#clicks_"+dataId).html(clicks);
});

$(".dec").on("click", function (){
    var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var clicks = parseInt($("a#clicks_"+dataId).html());

    if (clicks > 0) {
        clicks--;
    }
    $("a#clicks_"+dataId).html(clicks);
});
</script>
```